# How do I open the door in the cave between Bree and Hobbiton?

Tags: lego-lord-of-the-rings

I found a key to open the first door, but no characters seem to be able to interact with the door inside.
Also, what will I find once I'm past the door?

Comment: What does the door look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you find the key by fishing? If so once you have the key Aragon or Isildor should be able to smash the morgul bricks